# How can I make Python 3.4 subtract from a score?

Tags: python

I am making a small gambling game in Python where you start off with 500 dollars, but I want to subtract your money when you use it. I have money += irand (irand being the money you make from gambling) but I don't know how to subtract the money from the string money. Any help? Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
import os
import time
import math
from random import randrange, uniform
#CLS
def cls():
    os.system('cls')
#Main Game
def casino():
    money = 500
    print ("You have $500 dollars to start with.")
    time.sleep(3)
    while True:
        bet = input ("How much money do you wish to bet?: ")
        if bet >= '1' or bet <= '50':
            irand = randrange(0, 101)   
            print ("Your earnings are $%s" % irand + "!")
            time.sleep(3)
            money += irand
            print ("You now have $%s" % money + "!")
            time.sleep(4)
            cls()
            continue
        if bet >= '51' or bet <= '100':
            irand = randrange(0, 201)
            print ("Your earnings are $%s" % irand + "!")
            time.sleep(3)
            money += irand
            print ("You now have $%s" % money + "!")
            time.sleep(4)
            cls()
            continue
        if bet >= '101' or bet <= '150':
            irand = randrange(0, 301)
            print ("Your earnings are $%s" % irand + "!")
            time.sleep(3)
            money += irand
            print ("You now have $%s" % money + "!")
            time.sleep(4)
            cls()
            continue
        if bet >= '151' or bet <= '200':
            irand = randrange(0, 401)
            print ("Your earnings are $%s" % irand + "!")
            time.sleep(3)
            money += irand
            print ("You now have $%s" % money + "!")
            time.sleep(4)
            cls()
            continue
        if bet >= '201' or bet <= '250':
            irand = randrange(0, 501)
            print ("Your earnings are $%s" % irand + "!")
            time.sleep(3)
            money += irand
            print ("You now have $%s" % money + "!")
            time.sleep(4)
            cls()
            continue
#Intro to Game - Optional
def intro():
    print ("CMD Casino is a small CMD game that simulates a gambling game.")
    time.sleep(4)
    print ("Just type in a money value and the game will determine if you make or lose out on your bet.")
    time.sleep(4)
    cls()
#Main Code
def main():
    print ("Please select an option when prompted!")
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print ("[1] Casino")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print ("[2] How-To")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print ("[3] Exit")
        time.sleep(1)
        menu = input ("Please Choose: ")
        cls()
        time.sleep(1)
        if menu == '1':
            casino()
        if menu == '2':
            intro()
        if menu == '3':
            print ("Exiting the game...")
            time.sleep(2)
            break
            SystemExit

#Launch Code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("CMD Casino")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("By: Oiestin")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("In hand with: oysterDev")
    time.sleep(4)
    cls()
    print ("Version Beta 1.0.0")
    time.sleep(4)
    cls()
    main()
```

Comment: What does it mean to "subtract money from the string money"?

Comment: share your code, otherways this will never work out

Comment: @ScottHunter I am assuming money is a string. (I am new to Python so I am not sure.) But when you start the game, money is equal to 500 dollars. And when I bet 5 dollars, I want to remove 5 dollars from money.

Comment: `money = str(float(money)- float(spent_money))`?
Though `money` should be `int` or `float`. Don't you think?

Comment: change the start of your casino function to this, http://pastebin.com/Q0hdqEEZ, your `SystemExit` should be `SystemExit()` but either way it is unreachable after your break

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not going to work, because you are trying to use mathematical operators like `>=`, etc. to compare string values, which will result in unexpected (for you) results. Instead, all monetary values should either be ints or floats to begin with, and you should cast your `input()` values to ints or floats as well, in order for the math to work correctly.

Just to illustrate:

```
>>> "20" > "1000"  # because 50 (ord("2")) is > 49 (ord("1"))
True
```

Comment: thanks @Tim, I was just going to put something like that in :)